# Htmlentities Encode and specific Decode

Tags: php, html-entities, html-encode, html-escape-characters

I create a blog where people can be create a post with scripts code.
So i pass the post string in `htmlentities($string)` during upload and save it into database. Now, this work but only with scripts code.
I'll explain:

**If i post this:**

```
Letter: è ò à ù funzionerà

Script:

<script>alert('tornerò, arriverà')</script>
```

**Return:**

```
Letter: Ã¨ Ã² Ã  Ã¹ funzionerÃ 

Script:

<script>alert('tornerÃ², arriverÃ ')</script>
```

I try with `html_entity_decode($string)` but it decode all string, and scripts disappears (obviously)

How can i decode only "special characters"? I think to str_replace to decode only those characters but i'm searching for faster way, if it exists!?

Comment: Is the 'return' situation sending text to the blog webpage from the database? Also, is AJAX involved?

Answer (score 0):

It might be not the ideal answer, but i suggest you take a look at your 'output file' encoding, database encoding and the meta charset. I have a couple of Norwegian, swedish and danish sites. Which all work fine without encoding and decoding stuff.

Comment: if I used htmlspecialchars () instead htmlentities ()? which causes could happen?

Comment: htmlsepcialchars do the opposite from what you want. It replaces only & < > ' and "". Which are quite important HTML entities. There for there is function which does that so i can't be handled as code.

Comment: Actually, my only fear is to prevent scripts injection and even more important, maintain special characters legible. So, htmlspecialchars() at this moment is the best way.

Comment: I dont want to sound like a complete dushbag, but the only fully legit way of preventing SQL Injections is escaping using the mysqli/pdo mysql escape system. Just to let you know :-)

Comment: I already used mysql_real_escape_string to upload strings, but on call returned as empty string and scripts started (for example <script>alert('error')</script>). Are there cleaner systems?